# Python: count the numbers between a range that are divisible by another integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

> Detail: User enters 3 integers as numX >= numY >= numZ. Count how many
> integers between the range of numX and numZ that are divisible by
> numY (while loop required).

This is a practice question from my course worksheet and here are the codes I wrote for which I can't get the correct answer.

```
print("Enter 3 integer numbers, where as numX ≥ numY ≥ numZ")
x = int(input("numX: "))
y = int(input("numY: "))
z = int(input("numZ: "))

oldx = x
oldy = y
oldz = z
ctr = 0
while x >= y >= z:
    if x % y == 0 or z % y == 0:
        ctr = ctr + 1
    x = x - 1
    z = z + 1
print(f"There are {ctr} numbers in {oldx}...{oldz} that are divisible by {oldy}")
```

Thank you in advance for any helpful tips.

Comment: Add sample input and output

Comment: @Sabil ```Enter 3 integer numbers, where as numX ≥ numY ≥ numZ.
numX: 12
numY: 3
numZ: 2
There are 4 numbers in 2...12 that are divisible by 3.```

Comment: Hint: what happens when both `x` and `z` are divisible by `y`?

Comment: Another possible hint: Python's `range` function takes start, stop, and step arguments.

Comment: @JacobIRR there's no `range` in this code, probably appropriate since the instructions were to use `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were increasing `z` value and decreasing `x` value. You shouldn't do that. If you increase `z` value then it will not execute between the actual range. You don't even need the old variables.

So, I think the following code snippet will work for you.

**Code:**

```py
print("Enter 3 integer numbers, where as numX ≥ numY ≥ numZ")
x = int(input("numX: "))
y = int(input("numY: "))
z = int(input("numZ: "))

oldx = x

ctr = 0
while x >= y >= z:
    if x % y == 0:
        ctr += 1
    x -= 1
print(f"There are {ctr} numbers in {oldx}...{z} that are divisible by {y}")
```

**Output:**

```
Enter 3 integer numbers, where as numX ≥ numY ≥ numZ
numX: 12
numY: 3
numZ: 0
There are 4 numbers in 12...0 that are divisible by 3
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction! Does it mean if I add ```z += 1```, I would've missed when both ```x``` and ```z``` are divisible by ```y```? And why ```numZ``` can't be entered as 0?

Comment: If you set `z` as `0` then based on your condition it will increase the count. `0` is divisible by any number so it will not provide our desired output. Hope you understand.